# Coming from Java, C#, if C++ has no event handling, how does one catch when something happens?

Tags: java, c#, c++, events, listeners

Java and C# differ in their respective event handling techniques. In Java you write interfaces or classes that your program can call. In C# it is done differently using events and delegates.

Does C++ have some form of event handling?

My understanding is in Java events are done like this:

```
class Class1
{
     private ArrayList<MyEventListener> listeners;

     //Class stuff

     public void doEvent () {for(MyEventListener e : listeners) {e.eventHappened(args);}

     public void addToListeners(MyEventListener eventListener) {listeners.add(eventListener);
     public void removeFromListeners(MyEventListener eventListener) {listeners.add(eventListener);
     public interface MyEventListener
     {
          void eventHappend (Anything passable);
     } 
}
```

I imagine C++ it could be done similiarly

```
Define new Class
{
    Define Array (Java ArrayList/List) of the abstract class or interface below

    //Define other unrelated class stuff

    Define add to listeners function

    Define remove from listeners function

    Define inner interface (maybe a C++ abstract class would work instead as interfaces don't exist in C++) to act as event

           Define function in inner abstract event class to be the actual part of the code that represents the event

    Define call all listeners function
}
```

Does this make sense? I honestly can not see how one could program anything without an event listener/handler system, I assume I am close.

How have you dealt with events having come from another language?

Comment: Look into design patterns.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "have some proper event handling".

Comment: C++ as a language has no idea of events at all.

Comment: If I am not completely wrong, also Java as a language is not aware of events, it is just the mainstream way of implementing stuff.

Comment: @tobi303 In that case, my definition of events above would work. Closest thing to an answer I have got.

Comment: I will formulate it as an answer and then the up/down voters will tell if it is a good answer ;)

Comment: It sounds like you're heading in a good direction here with your design. Why not actually try it and see if it works?  You might also consider searching for "the observer pattern in C++" and looking into how events work in COM by searching for IConnectionPoint.

Comment: See also the [boost signals2 library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ just as Java don`t have a built-in event mechanism. It is just a design pattern that you can implement in many other languages as well. The direct translation of your Java event mechanism could look like this:

```
class Class1 {
private:
     std::vector<MyEventListener*> listeners;

public:
    void doEvent () {
        for(MyEventListener* e : listeners) {e->eventHappened(args);
    }
    void addToListeners(MyEventListener* eventListener){
        listeners.push_back(eventListener);
    }
    void removeFromListeners(MyEventListener* eventListener){
        listeners.push_back(eventListener);  // same bug as in your java version :P
    class MyEventListener {
        virtual void eventHappend (Anything passable) = 0;
        virtual ~MyEventListener(){}
    }; 
};
```

Comment: I think the main difference is that java uses the pattern in its standard library, whereas c++ doesn't (probably becaus it doesn't hav any gui classes). But e.g. Qt's Signal-Slot-concept is basically exactly that.

Comment: @MikeMB I think in detail Qts signal-slot mechanism is quite different, as the obejct that emits the signal does not need to know anything about the objects that recieves it

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it does - after the moc process, it has a list of objects that are connected to a specific signal. But I have to admit, I'm not familiar with the implementation details.

Comment: Thank you. I am not new to C++, but it has been a few years. This is exactly what I was referring to. Your editted version is even better than the original!